# find short text's model

Tags: python, topic-modeling

I have a CSV file(like 1.3GB) and a column is about the short text. I want to do topic modeling for all short texts. But I don't know what should I do? I have tried the LDA method, but my data is too large I can not run it. By the way, I want to achieve this: the input is a short text and the output is some Exact categories or one category. (Sport, politics, entertainment, and so on)Can someone give me some idea? Code will be better! Thanks！

Comment: Have you tried anything Max ? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Yes, I have tried the LDA method. But my data is too large and I can not run the code on my computer.

Comment: I am a beginner to use stack overflow so thank you for replying to my question. It makes me feel better!